# Combining two filters when clicking two different sections of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to combine two filters when clicking two different sections of buttons. Right now, when I click one button it removes the selection of the previous one. I have tried several functions but I have not been able to come with the right logic.

I have written a schema of my current status.

HTML

```
<!-- Buttons -->

<p> Language: <button class="btn" data-category="en"> EN </button> <button class="btn" data-category="it"> IT </button> </p>
<p> Stuff: <button class="btn" data-category="a"> A </button> <button class="btn" data-category="b"> B </button> <button class="btn" data-category="c"> C </button> </p>

<!-- Elements to select -->

  <div class="element en a">
    <p>en A</p>
  </div>

  <div class="element en b">
    <p>en B</p>
  </div>

  <div class="element it c">
    <p>it C</p>
  </div>

  <div class="element it b">
    <p>it b</p>
  </div>
```

js / jQuery

```
$(".btn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var category = $(this).data("category")
  $('.element').hide();
  $('.element.'+category).fadeIn();
})
```

It's also in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d39xv7cg/3/).

Also, nice to haves:

- I would like to know how to color the button once it is selected.
- Add a reset button (which I guess would be easy adding "reset" in data-category.

Thanks for the advice and the suggestions in advance!

Comment: You are going to need to create a way to know which of each sub group is selected, if at all.  Then when someone clicks a button, you find all the buttons that are marked as selected, and perform your filter.  This could be potentially done by putting a class on them and finding the elements with that class.  However I would highly suggest you reduce your question and remove the "also, nice to haves".  Your question should be limited in scope to a single problem, otherwise it leans towards being too broad.

Comment: Another way of knowing which option in a group is selected would be if you converted the buttons to radio buttons, provided only one option in a group is allowed to be selected at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `radio` buttons. They allow one selection per group.

One downside is that you can't uncheck a radio button unless its by selecting another one in the same group, so I've added a "reset" button to each group.

Upon selection, I'm building a selector string of classes based on the checked buttons.

```js
$(".mycb input").on('change', function(e) {

  // select all the checked buttons.
  var $checked = $('.mycb :checked');
  
  // build an array of all the checked values.
  var checked_classes = $checked.map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).toArray();
  
  // add the baseline "element" class to the array.
  checked_classes.unshift('.element');
  
  // build the class selector string.
  var classes=checked_classes.join('.');
  
  // debug the class selector string.
  // console.log(classes);
  
  // hide all elements.
  $('.element').hide();
  
  // show the elements that match the class selector string.
  $(classes).fadeIn();
  
});

$('.reset').on('click', function() {
  var $container = $(this).closest('p');
  $('input', $container).prop('checked', false).last().trigger('change');
});
```

```css
btn-selected {
  color: red;
}

.mycb input {
  display: none;
}

.mycb span {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: .3em;
  padding: 0 .3em;
  cursor:pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.mycb input:checked+span {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button -->

<p>Language:
  <label class="mycb">
    <input type="radio" name="lang" value="en">
    <span>EN</span>
  </label>
  <label class="mycb">
    <input type="radio" name="lang" value="it">
    <span>IT</span>
  </label>
  <span class="mycb reset"><span>Reset</span></span>
</p>

<p>Stuff:
  <label class="mycb">
    <input type="radio" name="stuff" value="a">
    <span>A</span>
  </label>
  <label class="mycb">
    <input type="radio" name="stuff" value="b">
    <span>B</span>
  </label>
  <label class="mycb">
    <input type="radio" name="stuff" value="c">
    <span>C</span>
  </label>
  <span class="mycb reset"><span>Reset</span></span>
</p>

<!-- Elements to select -->

<div class="element en a">
  <p>en A</p>
</div>

<div class="element en b">
  <p>en B</p>
</div>

<div class="element it c">
  <p>it C</p>
</div>

<div class="element it b">
  <p>it b</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have forked your js fiddle to provide a solution using your CSS class

https://jsfiddle.net/sguex20k/

JavaScript

```
$('.btn').removeClass('btn-selected'); // resetting all buttons to remove class

/* other code */

$(this).addClass('btn-selected'); // adding class to clicked button
```

And the problem in your CSS you were missing the `.` in your selector

```
.btn-selected { }
```